# Orientate page horizontally?

Tags: tables

Is it possible to make on table to be oriented horizontally?
I have a big table that I need to fit on one table and this is only way it can be done (except of using VERY small font).

Comment: Googling 'landscape table latex' returns [this Wikibooks page,](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_orientation) among others. Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=8cm,hmargin=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\newgeometry{vmargin=6cm,hmargin=8cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|*{10}{m{1cm}|}}\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: `pdflscape` is the way to go. I don't think changing the geometry is really required in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to load the **rotating** package, which provides the **sidewaystable** environment. Inside a sidewaystable environment, all table-related commands work just as they would in a table environment.