# Change size of one page to A3 in a document with papersize of A4

Tags: paper-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document)

I've a document where I need to add a map as a figure. Unfortunately the map is best viewed in A3 size. Therefore I wonder if this is possible with latex.

Comment: Have a look on [Change paper size in mid-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document). However I personally would like to see better solutions.

Comment: Maybe, if your document will be printed two sides, you could split your map up in two parts, print the first one on the verso page and the second part on the recto page, like they do in magazines.

Comment: rberaldo, the whole document is one side. and it is my thesis, the official way would be to print it to a A3 and to fold it two times. thank you

Comment: this issue seems to be really a problem. I thik I have to resize it to fit into an A4.

Comment: How about this post on how to [Orientate page horizontally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23324/orientate-page-horizontally)? It still uses `geometry`...

Comment: This issue is *not* "really a problem". With pdflatex it is easy to change the pdf page size for single pages in a pdf and to insert e.g. large maps. But a pdf is only a file, a "virtual" document. You will have to consider how you will get the A3-page printed and inserted in your real world document.

Comment: @Ulrike: exactly as it is seen in the "virtual" document

Comment: @adnc Sure, but how will you do it practically? Do you have a printer with an A4 and a A3 tray which can change trays during a printing job? Or will you give your pdf to an external print shop? Will they be able to handle the A3 page? Or will you split the print job?

Comment: @Ulrike, actually it can be of any type. Even within two different pdf-files. All I want is having the A3 page look as part of the rest, with the header and the page numbering.

Comment: But you obviously still didn't test the pratical side. Take the document below from ozl23, fill it with some text (`lipsum`-package), perhaps add the option `paper=landscape` and `paper=portrait` then generate the pdf. Try to print it. - Regarding the header: where do you want it? On the large or the small side of the a3 page? Should it have the same size than on the a4 or be magnified somehow? Do you really want to number it? Take a real book to try out what would look best.

Comment: @ulrike, thank you. I tested the example already. But couldnt get this: The A3 page is going to be fold. So ideally the header and the page number in the footer (as in the rest) would be on the right half of the A3 page. The map I have fits nice into a landscape A3. So if you fold out  and close the bind document the right half of the A3 page stays outside and show the header and page number in the footer.

Comment: Sounds odd. I would (if I would use headers at all) put them on the left side like this: `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\begingroup
\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{2\textwidth}{10cm}}

A very large image.
\clearpage
\endgroup
\lipsum
\end{document}` If you want them right, enlarge `\oddsidemargin`

Comment: For a printing challenges you can order your job like "Print all except pages..." or create separate document without those pages, tune page numbering and large ones print separately. If you are about to print hundreds of copies, you should consult it with DTP specialist. I think this question is about creating file, that will be viewed on screen.

Answer (score 3):

I just googled ... did not try it myself though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document

Try this, I am also curios to know if it works:

```
\documentclass[version=last, pagesize=auto, paper=a4]{scrartcl}
  \begin{document}

  \null
  \clearpage

   \KOMAoptions{paper=a3}
   \recalctypearea

   \null
   \clearpage

   \KOMAoptions{paper=a4}
   \recalctypearea

   \null

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score -3):

The geometry package lets you change page geometry in mid-document.

But be aware that this will almost certainly mess up printing unless you have a dual-size printer (and I don't know if the geometry package will do this switch for you).

Comment: No `geometry` does not allow the change of the paper size mid document. It includes explicit code which stops you to do so. See the quote in [Change paper size in mid-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document).